# Embedded view results being lost when form_set_error is being called

Tags: 7, views, forms

I have a page (user profile.tpl.php) with a custom form and a view embedded in the tpl.php file.

The custom form is defined in a custom module, with validation and submit hooks, and the view is being displayed programatically like so:

```
$view = views_get_view('accounts_for_user');
$view->set_display('panel-pane-1');
$view->set_exposed_input(array('field_customer_number_uid' => $user->uid));
echo $accountsView->preview();
```

The form is also being displayed programatically (in a jquery ui dialog):

```
echo drupal_render(drupal_get_form('custom_mod_change_password_form'));
```

This is my validation hook:

```
function custom_mod_change_password_form_validate($form,&$form_state)
{    
    $oldPassword = $form_state['input']['old-password'];
    $newPassword1 = $form_state['input']['new_pass1'];
    $newPassword2 = $form_state['input']['new_pass2'];

    if ($newPassword1 != $newPassword2)
    {
        form_set_error('old-password',t("Password and confirm password do not match."));
    }
    global $user;
    $account = user_load($user->uid);
    if (!user_check_password($oldPassword,$account))
    {
        form_set_error('new_pass1',t("Old password is invalid."));
    }
}
```

Now this works on initial load and displays fine. The problem is that when there is a validation error, the view shows it's no result message instead of the actual fields.

Any ideas on what might be the problem?